# Insert each value from multidimensional array into a database

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am using phpexcelreader to read an excel file and getting an multidimensional array in return.

Now I want to save that array of records into my database. I am getting the array but I don't understand how I can get each value into the database. Here is the array which I am getting

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => 'Date',
    2 => 'Customer Name',
    3 => 'Address',
    4 => 'Phone  Number',
    5 => 'Email ID',
    6 => 'Amount',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    1 => '41577',
    2 => 'Gary E. Ross',
    3 => 'daf, GA 31907',
    4 => '12344',
    5 => 'geross50@gmail.com',
    6 => 'CAD50',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    1 => '41577',
    2 => 'JEAN h. LUGAR',
    3 => '123, N.C, 28312',
    4 => '111111',
    5 => 'jhlas@msn.com',
    6 => 'CAD143.28',
  )
```

This is the code I wrote to get the array above

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_path))
{
    $read_excel="upload/".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    //echo $read_excel;
    $excel = new PhpExcelReader;
    $excel->read($read_excel);
    $data = $excel->sheets[0];
     $excelArray = $excel->sheets[0]['cells'];
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($excel->sheets[0]['cells']);
    echo '</pre>';

     foreach($excelArray as $key=>$record)
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=count($record);$i++)
        {
            if(isset($record[$i])){
            echo $record[$i]. "</br>";
        }

        }

        /* foreach($record as $innerKey => $innerRecord)
        {   
            echo $innerRecord. "</br>";
        }  */ 
    } 

}
```

I am using foreach to get the values but it is not giving me the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

To get values in array, try like this,

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key1 => $val1) {
         echo $val1[$key1];
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get all the values from $val1?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($excelArray as $key=>$val) {
    $insertData='';
    foreach ($val as $key1 => $value) {
        $insertData.= "'".$value."',";
    }
    echo $query = $insertData;
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Uninitialized string offset

Comment: okay I got it but the problem is still same How can I save this in database. I am getting complete list of all the values of excel. How can I save each array's value in database separately

Comment: Hey you only implement it.   $insertData='';
  foreach ($excelArray as $key=>$val) {
    foreach ($val as $key1 => $value) {
         $insertData.= "'".$value."',";
   
    }
 echo $insertData;
 echo "<br/><br/>";
}

Comment: after foreach put on break. so you will get batch value. Then you will format whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
<?php
$array = array (
          1 => 
          array (
            1 => 'Date',
            2 => 'Customer Name',
            3 => 'Address',
            4 => 'Phone  Number',
            5 => 'Email ID',
            6 => 'Amount',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            1 => '41577',
            2 => 'Gary E. Ross',
            3 => 'daf, GA 31907',
            4 => '12344',
            5 => 'geross50@gmail.com',
            6 => 'CAD50',
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            1 => '41577',
            2 => 'JEAN h. LUGAR',
            3 => '123, N.C, 28312',
            4 => '111111',
            5 => 'jhlas@msn.com',
            6 => 'CAD143.28',
          )
);

echo "<b>\$array values:</b><br/><br/>";

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key1 => $val1) {
         //you will get values here.
        echo "<pre>$key1 => $val1</pre>";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}

?>
```

**Output:**

```
$array values:

1 => Date
2 => Customer Name
3 => Address
4 => Phone  Number
5 => Email ID
6 => Amount

1 => 41577
2 => Gary E. Ross
3 => daf, GA 31907
4 => 12344
5 => geross50@gmail.com
6 => CAD50

1 => 41577
2 => JEAN h. LUGAR
3 => 123, N.C, 28312
4 => 111111
5 => jhlas@msn.com
6 => CAD143.28
```

---

**To insert the records into database, you'd use following code:**

```
<?php
    $a=array (
      1 => 
      array (
        1 => 'Date',
        2 => 'Customer Name',
        3 => 'Address',
        4 => 'Phone  Number',
        5 => 'Email ID',
        6 => 'Amount',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        1 => '41577',
        2 => 'Gary E. Ross',
        3 => 'daf, GA 31907',
        4 => '12344',
        5 => 'geross50@gmail.com',
        6 => 'CAD50',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        1 => '41577',
        2 => 'JEAN h. LUGAR',
        3 => '123, N.C, 28312',
        4 => '111111',
        5 => 'jhlas@msn.com',
        6 => 'CAD143.28',
      ));

      $columns=$a[1];
      $range=count($a);
      $start=min(array_keys($a))+1; 
      $j=0;

      //echo "<pre>";print_r($a[$start]);exit; 
      for($i=$start; $i<= $range; $i++){
        $data="   ";
        $data.="(";
        foreach($a[$i] as $k=>$v){
            $data.="'".$v."', ";
        }
        $data=substr($data, 0,-2);
        $data.=")";
        $dataArray[$j]=$data;
        $j++;
      }

    $columnsName="( '".implode('\',\'',$columns)."' )";
    $values=implode(',',$dataArray);

    echo $query="INSERT INTO `table_name` ".$columnsName." VALUES ".$values;


    // To insert the records in Database

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myDB"; // Database name

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error); //This will insert the records into database (table_name)

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Please mark this as answer if it helped you, Thank you. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, consider adding a little explanation to your code: why does it work? What does it do exactly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this its totally dynamic whether your fields append in future..

```
<?php
$a=array (
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => 'Date',
    2 => 'Customer Name',
    3 => 'Address',
    4 => 'Phone  Number',
    5 => 'Email ID',
    6 => 'Amount',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    1 => '41577',
    2 => 'Gary E. Ross',
    3 => 'daf, GA 31907',
    4 => '12344',
    5 => 'geross50@gmail.com',
    6 => 'CAD50',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    1 => '41577',
    2 => 'JEAN h. LUGAR',
    3 => '123, N.C, 28312',
    4 => '111111',
    5 => 'jhlas@msn.com',
    6 => 'CAD143.28',
  ));
  $columns=$a[1];
  $range=count($a);
  $start=min(array_keys($a))+1; 
  $j=0;
  //echo "<pre>";print_r($a[$start]);exit; 
  for($i=$start; $i<= $range; $i++){
    $data="   ";
    $data.="(";
    foreach($a[$i] as $k=>$v){
        $data.="'".$v."', ";
    }
    $data=substr($data, 0,-2);
    $data.=")";
    $dataArray[$j]=$data;
    $j++;
  }
$columnsName="( '".implode('\',\'',$columns)."' )";
$values=implode(',',$dataArray);
echo $query="Insert into".$columnsName." Values ".$values;  
  ?>
```

Comment: Insert into( 'Date','Customer Name','Address','Phone Number','Email ID','Amount' ) Values ('41577', 'Gary E. Ross', '3801, Gentian Blvd apt, 104, Columbus, GA 31907', '334-338-0286', 'geross50@gmail.com', 'CAD50'), ('41577', 'JEAN h. LUGAR', '334, GRAPE ARBOR DR. Fayetteville, N.C, 28312', '910-485-6541', 'jhlugar@msn.com', 'CAD143.28'), ('41575', 'Richard J Muschamp', '2, hidden lake way, palm coast, fl 32137', '503-318-9143', 'dick@custommicro.com', 'CAD149.99')

This is the result I am getting

Comment: so?? does not work it? i have prepared string for you once copy string and paste in your sql or phpmyadmin